# Creating an HTML table using JavaScript and JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to create an HTML table using JavaScript from a JSON input, however, it's not working out for me.

I am using a marker in the HTML. This will get populated from an `innerHTML` call in Javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
  listItem = json.data[i].number + "--" + "( Widget " + json.data[i].widget_id + ") x " + "  " + json.data[i].pence_price + " GBP" + json.data[i].number * json.data[i].pence_price + " GBP";
  table.push(listItem);
}
document.getElementById('updateOrder').innerHTML = table;
```

This gives me the following output:

```
11--Widget 8 x 10GBP 110GBP, 10--Widget 9 x 10GBP 100GBP
```

What I want is the following:

```
11--Widget 8 x 10GBP                  110GBP
10--Widget 9 x 10GBP                  100GBP
```

Where the number, widget and cost are left-aligned, and the total is right-aligned. I also want separate orders on separate lines.

The data in the JSON is:

```
{"id":"9518","order_id":"11380","widget_id":"9","number":"10","pence_price":"12"}
```

I've been pulling my hair out with this; any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any table in there, neither do I see a something like flex, what I see you are pushing something inside an array (from which the declaration is missing). So now you have a set of concatenated strings  instead... So how would you like your table to be build, as a html table or a with divs?

Comment: You are right, I want to put this into a table, but i only want to cherry pick certain json components. As you can tell, I am not particularly skilled in JS and would appreciate if what I have managed to cobble together can be turned into a table. PS. this is being written via  cordova for an android phone.

Comment: A tabular format without lines, if that is just by using divs - then yes by divs.

Comment: Thank you for editing my post, it looks like what I intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var json = {data:{a: {"id":"9518","order_id":"11380","widget_id":"9","number":"10","pence_price":"12"},b:{"id":"9518","order_id":"11380","widget_id":"9","number":"10","pence_price":"12"},c: {"id":"9518","order_id":"11380","widget_id":"9","number":"10","pence_price":"12"}}}
var i,
    item,
    listItem = "";
for (i in json.data){
    item = json.data[i];
    listItem += "<div class='table'><div>"+item.number+"--"+"( Widget "+item.widget_id+") x "+"  "+item.pence_price+" GBP</div><div class='right'>"+item.number*item.pence_price+" GBP</div></div>";
}
document.getElementById('updateOrder').innerHTML=listItem;
```

```css
#updateOrder{
  padding: 2px;
  background: orange;
}
.table{
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  display: table;
}
.table > div{
  display: table-cell;
}
.right{
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="updateOrder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a bit larges template which gives you a possible way to create a table, add some styling to it, and do some potential calculations.

I did my best to add as much comments as possible describing what the code is doing.

Since you mentioned you wanted an html table, it is created with the basic `table` element, and some basic styles were added to differentiate between header, rows and footer

```js
// the data used in this demo
var data = [{
    "id": "9518",
    "order_id": "11380",
    "widget_id": "9",
    "number": "10",
    "pence_price": "12"
  },
  {
    "id": "9518",
    "order_id": "11380",
    "widget_id": "9",
    "number": "10",
    "pence_price": "12"
  }
];

function createTable(target, data, columns) {
  // gets the elements required based on id for the target div
  // and creates the table, thead, tbody & tfoot for the table
  let element = document.getElementById(target),
    table = document.createElement('table'),
    thead = document.createElement('thead'),
    header = document.createElement('tr'),
    tbody = document.createElement('tbody'),
    tfoot = document.createElement('tfoot');

  // creates the header
  columns.forEach(column => {
    // and creates the cells in the header, adding title and class
    let cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.innerHTML = column.title;
    cell.className = column.class;
    header.appendChild(cell);
  });
  thead.appendChild(header);

  // totals is used for the totals for the footer
  var totals = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // creates the single rows
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    columns.forEach(column => {
      // and for each column creates the cell itself
      let cell = document.createElement('td');
      let value;
      // checks what to display
      if (column.field) {
        // only a property on the data
        value = data[i][column.field];
      } else if (column.value) {
        // a function with a callback value
        value = column.value(data[i])
      }
      // if it should calculate totals, it will do so here
      if (column.calculateTotal) {
        // in case the column is unknown, it's initialized as 0
        // warning: all values will be whole numbers
        totals[column.field] = (totals[column.field] || 0) + parseInt( value );
      }
      // if it has a template, we will replace the %0 with value
      // this template function supports only 1 value to be "templated"
      if (column.template) {
        value = column.template.split('%0').join(value);
      }
      // set the cell value
      cell.innerHTML = value;
      // set the class (used to align, for example)
      cell.className = column.class;
      // add cell to row
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    // add row to tbody
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
  // empty object would mean false, so only if totals needed to be calculated
  // would it create the footer here
  if (totals) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    columns.forEach( column => {
      let cell = document.createElement('td'), value = '';
      if (column.calculateTotal) {
        value = totals[column.field];
        if (column.template) {
          // can still use the row template
          value = column.template.split('%0').join(value);
        }
      }
      cell.innerHTML = value;
      cell.className = column.class;
      row.appendChild( cell );
    });
    tfoot.appendChild( row );
  }
  table.appendChild(thead);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  table.appendChild(tfoot);
  // set the table on the target element
  // warning, calling create table twice will create 2 tables under eachother
  element.appendChild(table);
}

// call the create table, with the:
// - target: id in html -> 'target'
// - data: an array defining your data itself 
// - columns: an array of objects describing how the table should look
//    - title: header
//    - field (optional): which property it should show
//    - value (optional): callback function that receives a row and should return a value
//    - calculatedValue (optional): bool indicating if columns should be summed
//    - template (optional): any text you wish to add to your data?
createTable('target', data, [{
    title: 'id',
    field: 'id',
    class: 'left'
  },
  {
    title: 'order',
    field: 'order_id',
    class: 'left'
  },
  {
    title: 'widget',
    field: 'widget_id',
    class: 'left'
  },
  {
    title: 'number',
    field: 'number',
    class: 'center'
  },
  {
    title: 'price',
    field: 'pence_price',
    class: 'right',
    template: '%0 GBP'
  },
  {
    title: 'total',
    value: (row) => parseInt(row['number']) * parseInt(row['pence_price']),
    class: 'right',
    template: '%0 GBP',
    calculateTotal: true
  }
]);
```

```css
.left {
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
thead tr {
  background-color: #777;
}
thead tr td {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
tfoot tr td {
  font-weight: bold;
}
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid #efefef 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Icepickle for your time, this also worked, however the answer from avril above was easier for me to implement.

Comment: @KevinSullivan Cool :) As long as you have found your answer, all is good :) I also created the sample code based on your first post, without the edits and how it should look and with the html table as you described. Though it's true avril's code is easier to use