# Table doesn’t appear with user data

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to build a table through a separate JS file and tie it to my HTML. This is my code:

```js
// Data for the "HTML Tables" Page

var users = [
  {
    first_name: "Kaitlin",
    last_name: "Burns",
    age: 23,
    email: "kburns99753@usermail.com"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Joshua",
    last_name: "Feir",
    age: 31,
    email: "josh319726@usermail.com"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Stephen",
    last_name: "Shaw",
    age: 28,
    email: "steve.shaw47628@usermail.com"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Timothy",
    last_name: "McAlpine",
    age: 37,
    email: "Timbo72469@usermail.com"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Sarah",
    last_name: "Connor",
    age: 19,
    email: "SarahC6320@usermail.com"
  }
];

window.onload = function() {
  loadTables();
};

function loadTables() {
  var selector = this.document.querySelector("#publicTable");
  var table = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + users.first_name[i] + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + users.last_name[i] + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + users.age[i] + "</td>" +
      "<td><a href=\"mailto:" + users[i].email + "\">" + users[i].email + "</></td>" +
      "</tr>";
  }
  
  selector.innerHTML += table;
}
```

```html
<table id="publicTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th> First Name </th>
    <th> Last Name </th>
    <th> Age </th>
    <th> Email </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the problem is that in my website, the code from the JS file is not inserted despite calling the ID of the table from the `querySelector`.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Each browser comes with a developer console where you can even set breakpoints to run your program step by step

Comment: `users.age[i]` vs `users[i].email`

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors, like “`TypeError: users.first_name is undefined`”. Also it’s `</a>`, not `</>`. And why are you prepending `this.` to `document`?

Comment: Maybe you could do some work in generalizing how you display your data, for example, with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924509/creating-an-html-table-using-javascript-and-json/43925208#43925208) or based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051277/duplicate-of-product-in-shopping-cart/45056349#45056349)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property access is wrong it should be `users[i].first_name` loop through the array and access each object property.

Your function should look like this:

```
function loadTables(){

    var selector = this.document.querySelector("#publicTable");

    var table = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){

        table += "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + users[i].first_name + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + users[i].last_name + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + users[i].age + "</td>" +
        "<td><a href=\"mailto:" + users[i].email + "\">" + users[i].email + "</></td>" +
        "</tr>";
    } 

    selector.innerHTML += table;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Abd Ellatif Lakehal.  I will accept your answer and give you and upvote.  If you think that this was a well-asked question, could you also give me an upvote?

Comment: Could you give me an upvote if you think that this was a well asked question?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in the loop, first select the fix position and then the property

```js
 var users = [
        {first_name: "Kaitlin", last_name: "Burns", age: 23, email: "kburns99753@usermail.com"},
        {first_name: "Joshua", last_name: "Feir", age: 31, email: "josh319726@usermail.com"},
        {first_name: "Stephen", last_name: "Shaw", age: 28, email: "steve.shaw47628@usermail.com"},
        {first_name: "Timothy", last_name: "McAlpine", age: 37, email: "Timbo72469@usermail.com"},
        {first_name: "Sarah", last_name: "Connor", age: 19, email: "SarahC6320@usermail.com"}
    ];
    
    window.onload = function(){
        loadTables();
    };
    
    function loadTables(){
            var selector = this.document.querySelector("#publicTable");
        
            var table = "";
        
            for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
                table+= "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + users[i].first_name + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + users[i].last_name + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + users[i].age+ "</td>" +
                "<td><a href=\"mailto:" + users[i].email + "\">" + users[i].email + "</></td>" +
                "</tr>";
            }selector.innerHTML += table;
    }
```

```html
<table id="publicTable" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Last Name </th>
                <th> Age </th>
                <th> Email </th>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: I have given you an upvote for your answer because it was correct, although someone else answered the same thing before you.  If you think that this was a well-asked question, could you also give me an upvote?

Comment: @OnurOzbek I was the first answer to your question, that's why I leave the page, you can check it here right at the end of the answer, it was sent, and compare them with the rest

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sorry.  I thought it was someone else.  Anyways, I've upvoted your answer because it still worked.  Could you upvote my question too?

Answer (score 1):

All you needed to do was fix the indexing.
Change `users.first_name[i]` to `users[i].first_name` and

`users.last_name[i]` to `users[i].last_name` and finally

`users.age[i]` to `users[i].age`.

You should be fine after making those changes.

```
function loadTables() {
  var selector = this.document.querySelector("#publicTable");

  var table = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + users[i].first_name + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + users[i].last_name + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + users[i].age + "</td>" +
        '<td><a href="mailto:' + users[i].email + '">' + users[i].email + '</>  </td>' +
      "</tr>";
  }
  selector.innerHTML += table;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/codejockie/pen/BrxQxO)

Comment: I've given you an upvote out of appreciation for your effort.  If you think that my question was well-asked, could you also give me an upvote?

Comment: @Onur Ozbek, I upvoted your question as it is valid.